# How can I run sqlcmd over all files in a folder using grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I have a folder to rebuild my database, and I need help running through the files. I followed Grunt's guide to making a "files" array (

```
grunt.initConfig({
    logfiles: {
        filesObject: {
            files: {
                'dist/file1.js': ['app/src*.js']
            }
        },
        filesArray: {
            files: [{
                src: ['app/src*.js'],
                dest: 'dist/file1.js'
            }]
        }
    }
});
grunt.registerMultiTask(
    'logfiles', 
    'Log the source-destination mappings in a Grunt multitask', 
    function() {
        this.files.forEach(function(file) {
            grunt.log.writeln('File ' + file.dest + ' has the sources ' + file.src);
        });    
    }
);
```

But I need to use it to convert the following grunt command into a "foreach" file:

```
 rebuildObjects: {
            cmd: "sqlcmd "
                + " -S .\\sqlexpress"
                + " -d " + Database
                + " -i file
                + " -v DATABASE_NAME = " + Database
```

The trouble I'm having is when I registerMultiTask I can't seem to call the rebuildObjects function, I have to make a Javascript Function, and when I registerTask, I seem to have trouble populating the Files array.

I would like to convert this to something like this:

```
rebuildObjects {
    this.files.forEach(function(file) {
        file.forEach(function(arrayIndex) {
            cmd: "sqlcmd "
                + " -S .\\sqlexpress"
                + " -d " + Database
                + " -i file[arrayIndex]
                + " -v DATABASE_NAME = " + Database
        })
    })
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless anyone has a better answer, what I ended up doing was creating a subtask "logfiles" where I use grunt.file.write(file.dest, file.src) to write to the destination

```
    grunt.registerMultiTask(
    'logfiles',
    'Log the source-destination mappings in a Grunt multitask',
    function () {
        this.files.forEach(function(file) {
            grunt.file.write(file.dest, file.src);
        });

    }
);
```

I then did this:

```
            cmd:
                function() {

                    var cmdString = "sqlcmd "
                        + " -S .\\sqlexpress"
                        + " -d " + Database;

                    //Create SqlObjects
                    var array = grunt.file.read("gruntLog/sqlObjects.js").split(",");
                    if (array.length > 0 && array[0] !== "") {
                        array.forEach(function(file) {
                            if (file != undefined)
                                cmdString += " -i  " + file + "";
                        });
                    };
                    cmdString += " -v DATABASE_NAME = " + Database
                    return cmdString;
                }
```